# eval-when-compile statements not running in files required by compiled file

Tags: byte-compilation

I've got one file including

```
(eval-when-compile (require 'cl))
```

Some other files require this file, and also need to have `cl` required when they are byte-compiled.  This is not happening - this first file does not appear to know it is getting byte compiled, when it is required by other files that are getting byte compiled.  Is there a way to craft an `eval-when-compile` statement in this first file, such that files that require it to also require `cl` when they are getting byte compiled?

EDIT: Context of the question:

When I download `https://github.com/idris-hackers/idris-mode` and run `make build` to byte compile, I get warnings in two separate files, `idris-prover.el` and `idris-repl.el`.  Both of these files require `inferior-idris.el` which contains the line `(eval-when-compile (require 'cl))`.  If I add that line to the two files, the warnings disappear.  I am wondering if that would be the best solution to fix the warnings.  Warnings include:

```
idris-prover.el:224:44:Warning: `:ok' called as a function
idris-prover.el:239:19:Warning: `:error' called as a function
idris-prover.el:253:67:Warning: `t' called as a function
```

Comment: Just put the same thing in each of those files. (This file should anyway not need to know the details of just what each of its required files needs.)

Comment: Normally when A requires B which requires C and so on, everything defined by C is visible to A.  Suppose it's part of B's interface that C is required.  Is there a way for A to require B, such that B's `eval-when-compile` statements are processed just like A's are?

Comment: 1. No, there's no predefined way to do that, as far as I know. (But you can code anything computable using Lisp. ;-) ) 2. This has nothing to do with visibility or interfaces - your "normally" doesn't apply here.

Comment: I do not understand why my "normally" doesn't apply.  Isn't it the case that if C contains `(setq hello t)`, B contains `(require C)`, and A contains `(require B)`, then for succeeding lines in A, `hello` will be defined as `t`?

Comment: If A is being byte-compiled, why should `eval-when-compile` statements not be executed inside the packages that it requires?

Comment: 1. `(eval-wnen-compile (require 'B)` is not `(require 'B)`. 2. If you load or compile A then B gets loaded (and thus C gets loaded). Loading B is not the same as compiling B. See (elisp)[Named Features](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Named-Features.html). 

This looks like it might be an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - what is it that you are really trying to do?

Comment: Edited the question with the reason I'm asking.

Comment: i wonder if your file A is being byte-compiled, then the other `(require 'A)` are having their requires satisfied by the `.elc` (rather than `.el`) file.  and, for whatever reason, the `.elc` doesn't note the require?  you could test by removing `A.elc`.

Answer (score 1):

Those warnings indicate actual bugs (from the warnings, I'd guess that the code uses cl.el's `case` macro) which make the resulting byte-code incorrect.

`(eval-wnen-compile (require 'B))` applies only to the given file.
Every file which uses cl.el's macros should have such a line (tho I'd argue that it should first be changed to use `cl-lib` instead, of course).